# How do I change the data structure of an HDF5 file?

Tags: keras, h5py

I'd like to change the data structure of an existing HDF5 file.

Currently the information I'm interested in is stored in a h5py group. What I want is to have the information of that group to be in its own HDF5 file with the substructure unchanged but no upper level group, so that the information is directly accessible.

The current upper level structure of the file is:

```
model_weights            Group
optimizer_weights        Group
```

With `'model_weights'` the group I am interested in.

It contains:

```
batchnormalization_1   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   batchnormalization_1_beta   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_1_gamma   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_1_running_mean   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_1_running_std   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
batchnormalization_2   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   batchnormalization_2_beta   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_2_gamma   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_2_running_mean   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_2_running_std   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
batchnormalization_3   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   batchnormalization_3_beta   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_3_gamma   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_3_running_mean   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_3_running_std   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
batchnormalization_4   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   batchnormalization_4_beta   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_4_gamma   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>    
   batchnormalization_4_running_mean   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_4_running_std   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
batchnormalization_5   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   batchnormalization_5_beta   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_5_gamma   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_5_running_mean   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   batchnormalization_5_running_std   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
dense_1   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   dense_1_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   dense_1_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
dense_2   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   dense_2_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   dense_2_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
dense_3   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   dense_3_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   dense_3_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
dense_4   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   dense_4_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   dense_4_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
maxoutdense_1   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   maxoutdense_1_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   maxoutdense_1_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
maxoutdense_2   type:  <class 'h5py._hl.group.Group'>
   maxoutdense_2_W   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
   maxoutdense_2_b   type: <class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>
```

I prefer to not regenerate this file with Keras (the v1.0 upgrade changed the structure of the checkpoint callback) using a new flag to save the weights only. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a simpler way than inserting every h5py group and dataset in another empty file.